# BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel

I am running a Java (TIBCO EBX) in linux server with 192 GB RAM and we are constantly seeing Java process getting restarted and application will go into hang state, with High Memory alerts.

We had set the heap size as 176 GB and we are seeing Heap size is getting full after 10 hours of interval with memory utilization never going down.

If we restart the server, memory utilization will go down. We tried to obtain the Kdump for the server to analyze memory leaks, and in the `vmcore-dmesg.txt` file, we are seeing the following entries.

Can anyone suggest if this is causing our memory leak and how we can fix this issue ?

```
[  389.832835] SysRq : Trigger a crash
[  390.049124] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
[  390.050076] IP: [<ffffffffbb270326>] sysrq_handle_crash+0x16/0x20
[  390.050076] PGD 80000017c6c6e067 PUD 17fa9c8067 PMD 0
```

Our Kernel version is below :

```
$uname -r 
3.10.0-1062.52.2.el7.x86_64

$ uname -a
Linux sr001 3.10.0-1062.52.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 8 09:03:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: bit confused, how do we know it's the kernel leaking memory and not just your Java application (or anything else running on the server)?

Comment: The reason you're seeing that "BUG: unable…", by the way, is because something *asks* for that crash to happen, see the line directly above. The interesting log lines are almost certainly above what you shared with us.